# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' after overriding validate function

Tags: python, django

I customized the `validate` function inside `rest_framework_simplejwt` so that when a user is authenticated it can trigger the `user_logged_in` signal so I can see if a user is logged in or not.

The problem I have now is that when a user logs in but enters the incorrect login details I get the error message:

```
AttributeError at /api/token/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

This is the full trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
\tokens.py", line 176, in for_user
    user_id = getattr(user, api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Here is my validate function :

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        authenticate_kwargs = {
            self.username_field: attrs[self.username_field],
            "password": attrs["password"],
        }
        try:
            authenticate_kwargs["request"] = self.context["request"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)
        tokens = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=self.context['request'], user=user)

        if not api_settings.USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE(user):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                self.error_messages["no_active_account"],
                "no_active_account",
            )

        return {
            'refresh': str(tokens),
            'access': str(tokens.access_token),
            'user': str(user),
        }
```

This is the function that handles user login/authentication

Comment: You don't need to override the serializer to do that. You can simply set [UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#update-last-login) to `True` in the settings

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I would like to explicitly know if a user is logged in so I created a boolean field in my profile to indicate if the user is logged in. From my understanding LAST_LOGIN would only return the timestamp of the last time the user was logged in

Comment: A boolean field won't help you there. Unless you use a websocket or a polling mechanism figuring out whether a user is online is difficult. At most you can say the user had some activity within some time interval which you consider as them being online.